# searchbox not working on toggle of list

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql-server

In the below leader board: If I click on the weekly scorecard, weekly scores are displayed and if on Overall Scorecard,overall scores are displayed.

[image: lb11]

**issue:**
when the page loads weekly scorecard is displayed.

Now the **search box** works perfectly for the weekly scorecard,when I toggle and go to the overall Scorecard,the searchbox doesnot work.Please let me know where exactly is the mistake.

code involved :
for searchbox :

```html
<div id="search5back">

  <form method="get" action="/search" id="searchbox5">
  <input id="search52" name="q" type="text" size="40" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search an Employee ...." />
    </form>
</div>
```

**PHP involved for weekly scorecard:**

```html
 <div id="weeklylb" class="leadboardcontent">

   <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">
   <ol id = "myOL">
   <li>
   <mark>
  <?php  while( $toprow4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt4) ) {

  echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow4['rank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow4['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow4['pointsRewarded'] . "</span></div>";

  } ?>
   </mark>
   </li>
   </ol>
   </div>

     </div>
```

**PHP involved for overall scorecard:**

```html
<div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">

  <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">
  <ol id = "myOL">
  <li>
  <mark>
  <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {

  echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";

  } ?>
  </mark>
  </li>
  </ol>
  </div>

</div>
```

javascript involved (for searchbox) :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search52");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
  li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
  divs=li[0].getElementsByClassName("parent-div");
  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      a = divs[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
      if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          divs[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
          divs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can I have the HTML code for `Weekly Scorecard` and `Overall Scorecard`  tab as well?

Comment: @Perumal93 thanks for the input.In the above code you will see the "php involved for weekly scorecard" and ""php involved for overall scorecard" .That itself contains all the html u will need.

Comment: I've added answer. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Perumal93 thanks>i will get back to ya

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/41491284/1011527 (sock-puppet alert)

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search52");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

    var leadboardcontent_all = document.getElementsByClassName('leadboardcontent');
    for(var i = 0; i < leadboardcontent_all.length; i++) {
        if(leadboardcontent_all[i].style.display !== 'none') {
            leadboardcontent_visible = leadboardcontent_all[i];
        }
    }

    ol = leadboardcontent_visible.getElementsByClassName("myOL")[0];
    li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
    divs = li[0].getElementsByClassName("parent-div");

    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        a = divs[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            divs[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            divs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

There is a condition you need to check when you type in the input field. That is, you need to check if any of those tabs is visible or not. If one of the two is visible, perform a filter operation on that tab. Here, I have made an array of div's with the class of `leadboardcontent` and looping through them to check which of them is visible and the visible one is added to a new variable. Now, traversing through the descendant elements in that `leadboardcontent` element just by replacing

```
ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
```

with

```
ol = leadboardcontent_visible.getElementsClassName("myOL")[0];
```

since you're only traversing through the visible one. Note that, don't use `ID` for `ol` tags in your case. Instead, use `class` since you have more than one `ol` tag and also for same purpose.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for trying.But its not working.Now the searchbox works on none of the list. @Perumal93

Comment: the approach looks cool to me.Dnt know why aint working.Anyways,upvote coz u tried..!!